# Exponents Order of Operation

Tags: arithmetic

I'm still confused about order of operations on exponents:

Is $x^{a^b}$ equal to $x^{(a^b)}$ or $(x^a)^b$?

*Hmm... $x^{a^b}$ has the source of `x^{a^b}`. Whenever I try `x^a^b`, it requires me to "clarify by using braces".

Comment: Can anyone retag this "order-of-operations"?

Comment: Since that tag does not exist, and this is covered in arithmetic and elementary...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, it makes much more sense to use the convention $$a^{b^c} = a^{\left(b^c\right)}.$$ This is knows as "right associativity".

Comment: Awesome.  I joined this stackexchange to post a question, but find this during the close-sounding-question list.